# Date of Birth is not displaying in magento2 sales order create form in admin magento2

Tags: magento2.3.3, admin-order-create

Date of Birth is not displaying in magento2 sales order create form in admin magento2.

Even settings are enable for admin checkout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created this query to check the status of the date of birth attribute.
You just have to enter the attribute code and launch the query in the database. You will need to check if the "is_visible" value is set to 1.

```
select cea.*
from eav_attribute
left join catalog_eav_attribute cea on eav_attribute.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
where attribute_code = 'choosen_attribute_code'
and entity_type_id = 4;
```

Compare with another working attribute and try to understand what is missing.

Cheers